# Is there a way to pm an author and use the wait_for command to capture the value they type in?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm writing a discord bot using python to log options trade.  What I'm looking to do with my bot is when a user type execute a command, !opentrade, the bot would private message the user with a series of questions.  The bot would then capture the answer in a series of variables and use that to process the answer.  Is this possible or does it have to be in the channel where the command is called.  Additionally, is it by default multithread, meaning 2 or 3 people can call that command at the same time and it would fud up the answer

I have the following thus far and it isn't working:

```
async def opentrade(ctx):

def check(author):
    def inner_check(message): 
        if message.author != author:
            return False
        try: 
            int(message.content) 
            return True 
        except ValueError: 
            return False
    return inner_check

try:
    await ctx.author.send('Enter the underlying: ')
    underlying = await client.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx.author), timeout=30)
    print (underlying)
except Exception as err:
    await ctx.channel.send("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm looking to do with my bot is when a user type execute a command, !opentrade, the bot would private message the user with a series of questions. The bot would then capture the answer in a series of variables and use that to process the answer. Is this possible or does it have to be in the channel where the command is called.

Possible. You need to put the whole logic into the coroutine that executes the command.

> Additionally, is it by default multithread, meaning 2 or 3 people can call that command at the same time and it would fud up the answer

If you implement the checks properly it won't fud the answer. In your code you already implemented the logic that checks for the author so noone else can change it `def check(author)`.
When executing the commands multiple times by different users it will also not fud the answer since the threads are independent.

You should extend this check so it checks for a message in a DM channel. The way your check is written now the caller can DM the bot or respond in a guild text channel.

---

I'm not sure what's saved in the `ctx` variable but I'm certain it has a `message` attribute.

Try `await ctx.message.author.send()`. If you are running into an error provide the error log.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I've decided to go another route